# Full-text search on microsoft docs using Apache SolR

Tags: apache, file, solr, documents

Does Apache Solr allow for full text search on Microsoft documents such as word or powerpoint? if so, where can I find a tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Solr uses Apache Tika for content extraction and support the majority of file types.

You'll need to configure a handler in your solrconfig.xml.

Here's a good starting documentation with examples:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html